# Physical Meaning behind Diagonalizing the Stress Tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, stress-strain

In classical mechanics we have the inertia tensor I, when we diagonalize it we get this very nice physical meaning to our eigenvalues and eigenvectors in terms of the principle axes of rotation (sometimes principle sets of axes in the degenerate case) and an inertia for rotation about them. Is there any type of similar physical meaning to diagonalizing the stress tensor (Maxwell or Classical)?
$$$$ As an example (which I don't think I believe), maybe it represents a coordinate system where we have no shear.

Comment: Isn’t finding a state without shear pretty useful? And, of course, finding the maximum shear is pretty important as well.

Comment: Yes.  You are finding the principal directions of stress, and the magnitudes of the principal stresses.  I disagree with @JonCuster that you are finding a *state* of stress without shear.  On plenes not normal to the principal stress directions, there is always shear stress, unless the state of stress is isotropic or transversely isotropic.